# I imported a dataset in R, created through a survey, which has only numeric value in it. However, once I loaded it in R only NAs appears

Tags: r, import, dataset, numeric, na

I imported a dataset in R, but once I did that the value I got were only NAs, and all the numeric values from my csv file got "cancelled". I thought that it was a problem with factorisation and I tried to use stringasfactor= F, as well as  read.csv(file="habits.csv",header=TRUE,colClasses=c("numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric"))

But for this last code I get this error:

```
> datagpa <- read.csv(file="habits.csv",header=TRUE,colClasses=c("integer","integer","integer","integer","integer","integer","integer","integer","integer","integer","integer"))
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  scan() expected 'an integer', got '2018/10/192:32:52PMEET;3.5;8;3;50;53;0;0;8;8;10;10'
> getwd()
[1] "/Users/rachelepesce/Desktop/QRM/R"
> datagpa <- read.csv(file="habits.csv",header=TRUE,colClasses=c("integer","integer","integer","integer","integer","integer","integer","integer","integer","integer","integer"))
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  scan() expected 'an integer', got '2018/10/192:32:52PMEET;3.5;8;3;50;53;0;0;8;8;10;10'
> datagpa <- read.csv(file="habits.csv",header=TRUE,colClasses=c("numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric"))

Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '2018/10/192:32:52PMEET;3.5;8;3;50;53;0;0;8;8;10;10'
```

Does any of you know how to solve it ?

Comment: "csv" stands for "comma separate value". It looks like your data is separated by semicolons. So maybe `read.csv` isn't a good choice? Maybe `read.table` and specify the separator yourself? Also, surely you don't want that first column, a date-time, to be read as an integer or numeric, right?

Comment: The error is pretty clear, your csv seems to be formated with `;` and not `,`. Try function `read.csv2`. Furthermore, your first column seems to be a date.